# Unexpected token from babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am new to react and getting unexpected token error in my render() return code

```
 render() {

      return (
          <div className="todo">
                  <span>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.done}
                        onClick={this.handleClick}></input>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.text}
                        className={this.state.done ? 'done' : 'not-done'}
                        onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleSubmit}></input>
                    </span>
                  </div>);
}
```

when I use babel to compile my app.jsx by

```
npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --preset react-app/prod
```

It is throwing below error

```
SyntaxError: src/app.jsx: Unexpected token (35:14)
33 | 
34 |           return (
>   35 |               <div className="todo">
       |               ^
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you post your complete class code. There might be chance you forgot to add `bracket` or anything

Comment: here is my github repository https://github.com/Dmoment/react-todo-app

Comment: You need to `import React from 'react'` in App.jsx  . Without importing React you can't use react features

Comment: After importing also same error is there. Please help